# VS Report Designer Unable to Connect Datasets to Data Sources

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am trying out Visual Studio Report Designer for the first time. I have created a new project and connected to my Database, the connection test was successful.  Then I created a report and added the Data Source.  That test connection was successful as well.  Finally I tried to add this connection to create a data set, but I keep getting a connection/permissions error.

My current permissions are db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin, and db_owner.  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I also have a "dummy user" that I created that works just fine.  Why can't my real profile connect?  I would just use the dummy user to create this report, but I will need to be connecting to other servers that do not have this dummy user.

Error Message: Message box saying "Unable to connect to data source '[data source name]'."

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Sure, updated my question, but it is just a message box saying unable to connect to the data source.  I am guessing it has to do with permissions, I am just not sure which permissions.  I have an admin role for my database, but not for the system.  So I am thinking it must be a permission that must be set at a different level than my DB, just not sure what to kind of permission to request IT for.

Comment: You can test your username in a query in SSMS using CmdMode under the Query menu. `:setvar _server "Server1"
:setvar _user "***username***"
:setvar _password "***password***"
:setvar _database "master"
:connect $(_server) -U $(_user) -P $(_password)

USE [$(_database)];
GO`